# choice of initializer_list iterator definition

Tags: c++, c++11

Why `std::initializer_list<T>::iterator` is defined as a naked pointer `T const*` rather than a `random_access_iterator` concept ?

Comment: Pointers are random access iterators. I don't know what the standard says about `initializer_list` (after looking, I see that's the way they are in the standard), but it allows containers' iterators to be pointers.

Comment: @chris - sure but I'm wondering why it's different from all other standard containers.

Comment: For starters, this isn't a container. Perhaps simplicity was a factor. I can't say anything for certain.

Comment: @chris - you're right. the standard doesn't define initializer_list in the container library section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is probably from this little tid-bit from the standard

Section 18.9

> An object of type initializer_list provides access to an array of
>   objects of type const E. [ Note: A pair of pointers or a pointer plus
>   a length would be obvious representations for initializer_list.
>   initializer_list is used to implement initializer lists as specified
>   in 8.5.4. Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying
>   elements. —end note ]

This indicates that initializer_lists when copied will have pointer semantics and not value semantics, which is probably why their iterators are directly pointers and not wrapped into a "random-access-iterator" type.

AFAIK this is the only standard "*container*" (notice the quotes here), to have pointer semantics as opposed to value semantics.