# Can I rely on initializer_list::const_iterator being a plain pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, initializer-list

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518019/choice-of-initializer-list-iterator-definition) indicates that `std::initializer_list<int>::const_iterator` type is just a plain `int const*` pointer, but the wording of the standard as cited in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518061/4614700) (to the same question) sounds more like a suggestion than like a guarantee to me.

In my code, the problem occurs as follows: I have a function processing a sub-range of an `initializer_list`, and in a different situation I reuse the code from a convenience function passing a single element (as a single-element range):

```
void doStuff(int const* begin, int const* end)
{ ... do stuff ... }

  // main use; in the real code, 'init' is a parameter of a function
  std::initializer_list<int> init({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
  doStuff(init.begin() + 1, init.end());

  // alternative use of doStuff, relies on the pointer assumption
  int x = 6;
  doStuff(&x, (&x) + 1);
}
```

This construction relies on the fact that iterators are indeed pointers. It works at least with my clang++ 3.9 compiler. Can I rely on this to always work, i.e., is the pointer assumption portable? guaranteed to be portable? Or should I rather change the argument type of `doStuff` into a template parameter, to be on the safe side?

```
template <typename Iterator>
void doStuff(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{ ... do stuff ... }
```

Comment: From cppreference, it [seems you can](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). That is, either you can, or cppreference is wrong

Comment: @Justin Good point, but I cannot judge the source. Is it their reading of the standard, or is this website maintained by the standard committee? I did not find a definite source.

Comment: @tglas You can have a look at the current standard's draft (available at http://isocpp.org) and see §21.9.1.

Comment: Iterators are iterators. Assuming they are pointers or some other specific type is wrong. One *should not* make such assumptions in portable code (guaranteed or not). Just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on it, 18.9 from [C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) gives us inside `class initializer_list` the definitions:

`typedef const E* iterator;
typedef const E* const_iterator;`

Other types in C++ are different -- for example `std::vector`, where the iterator is implementation defined, and some implementations use a raw pointer as an iterator, and some use a class.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks!

Comment: I switched to C++14 anyway this morning, so that sounds like the definite answer.

Answer (score 4):

Section 18.9 of the standard gives a synopsis of the `<initializer_list>` header as follows:

> ```
> namespace std {
>   template<class E> class initializer_list {
>   public:
>     typedef E value_type;
>     typedef const E& reference;
>     typedef const E& const_reference;
>     typedef size_t size_type;
>     typedef const E* iterator;
>     typedef const E* const_iterator;
>     constexpr initializer_list() noexcept;
>     constexpr size_t size() const noexcept; // number of elements
>     constexpr const E* begin() const noexcept; // first element
>     constexpr const E* end() const noexcept; // one past the last element
>   };
>   // 18.9.3 initializer list range access
>   template<class E> constexpr const E* begin(initializer_list<E> il) noexcept;
>   template<class E> constexpr const E* end(initializer_list<E> il) noexcept;
> }
> ```

Furthermore, the `begin()` and `end()` functions on an `initializer_list` are guaranteed to return a `const E*`, as we can see from 18.9.2.

So yes, you can rely on it.

Comment: Note that not all synopsys are normative.